# ssas tabular model multiple facts

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm building a tabular model with multiple facts which are not related but using the same dimensions and exposing the model to power bi. The problem is after adding the second fact to the model, I'm not getting the correct values from the 1st fact.

Comment: Are the relationships defined as one way? Are the values immediately incorrect or only when you start adding dimensions? You need to do a lot more analysis than "I'm not getting correct values from first fact"

Comment: Yes, I'm using one-way relationships. Will provide detail analysis in near time